# Selection of at least two colours

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be three sketch pens of different colours. A regular pentagon is to be drawn using these colours where exactly one of the colours is used to draw a side and at least two colours are used to make the complete pentagon. In how many ways can this be done?

My attempt:

Each side can be drawn by using any of the three colours , so $3$ choices are available for each side. There are $5$ sides in total so they can be drawn in $3^{5}$ ways and the number of ways in which we can use only one colour is $3$ so the required number of ways $= 3^5 - 3$.

Did i miss anything?

Comment: Yes! A pentagon has 5 sides.  You say "they can be drawn in $3^5$ ways" and then include another way to color some, apparently, **sixth** way side!  What I would do is argue that there are $3^6$ ways to color the six sides so

Comment: @user247327 I did not understand what the problem is exactly, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're trying to say. Could you please be a little less vague?

Comment: You have assumed that the pentagon cannot be turned or flipped (i.e. that colouring the bottom line red and the rest green is a different pentagon from colouring the top left side red and the rest green). It's not wrong, but you should say this explicitly.

Comment: @Arthur As the question states that we  "draw" a pentagon so i assumed it to be 2-D.

Comment: In other words, is your pentagon labelled?

Comment: @Arthur what if we consider flipping ? In that case, what changes will occur ?

Comment: There would clearly be fewer pentagons, as many pentagons that your counting considers distinct would now be considered the same. Some of them would go together in groups of 5 and some in groups of 10. So the answer would be somewhere between 24 and 48, rather than 240.

Comment: Yes, i agree with your view on this. Each different side can be arranged in 5 possible ways, so accordingly, the answer should be $\frac{240}{5} = 48$

Comment: @Arshiya "*Each different side can be ... should be $\frac{240}{5}=48$*"  Be careful with that.  Although it appears to work that way for this problem (*if the only symmetries to consider are rotations*), the fact that $5$ is prime makes this a special case.  If the number of sides was not prime then you would need to be much more careful and use [Pólya's enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) or [The Lemma that is not Burnside's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$5$ sides and are given $3$ colors so we can take total no of functions which is $3^5$  required to use at least $2$ colors therefore  we get $3^5 - 3$. We got everything required but the ans is not yet over because they mentioned it is a regular polygon which means it has all side identical that is $5$ sides are identical . Hence the correct answer is $\frac{3^5 - 3} 5$

Answer (score -1):

Yes! A pentagon has 5 sides.  You say "they can be drawn in $3^5$ ways" and then include another way to color some, apparently, **sixth** way side!  What I would do is argue that there are $3^5$ ways to color the five sides but three of those ways include all five sides the same so there are $3^56- 3= 3(3^4-1)= 3(80)= 240 ways to do this.

Comment: I think $3^5 -3$ equals 240 as well.

Comment: `another way to color some, apparently, sixth way side`—I still can't parse this.  Where does this sixth choice come from?

Comment: If you're too late to edit your comment, you write a new one. The point of comments is to be a bit more fast-paced, and being able to go back and change a comment after a longer discussion is not ideal. So the edit time limit is a very good thing.

Comment: @user247327 i think what you've done is quite similar to my attempt.

Comment: @ Yanior Weg In a very polite manner, i have pointed it out that, what @user247327 has done is similar to my attempt and is not the answer i seek.

Answer (score -2):

since it is regular pentagon so anticlockwise and clockwise direction would be same so divide your answer by $5$ that is number of sides.

Comment: Please read this: [How to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656).